# Does this adaptive time-step algorithm have a name?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, numerical-optimization, adaptive-control

I'm using a somewhat unconventional technique to iteratively minimize a high-dimensional function $E(\vec\theta)$, and have proposed a simple routine to dynamically adapt its time-step. I am seeking to name/label this routine. If interested (though unrelated to my question) the technique is [*variational imaginary time evolution*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-019-0187-2.pdf?origin=ppub).

At each iteration, I compute

$\Delta \vec\theta = A^{-1} \nabla E(\vec\theta)$

and update the parameters

$\vec\theta \to \vec\theta +  \Delta \vec\theta \Delta t$.

Note that $A$ is *not* some straight-forward encoding of information of the space of $E(\vec\theta)$.

Under this scheme, for sufficiently small $\Delta t$, $E$ monotonically decreases. Previously I fixed $\Delta t$ at some empirically-determined stable value, but I now wish to determine it adaptively. Note that for my purposes, computing $\nabla E(\vec\theta)$ is expensive but computing $E(\vec\theta)$ is cheap. Ergo I can cheaply assess whether a chosen $\Delta t$ is good or bad, by calculating $\Delta E = E(\vec\theta + \Delta \vec \theta \Delta t)- E(\vec\theta)$.

I now propose my scheme.
Let $\Delta t$ be the time-step chosen in the previous iteration. Having computed $\Delta \vec\theta$ for this iteration, we seek to choose the new time-step. We will do so by repeatedly computing $\Delta E$ for new choices of $\Delta t$.

Repeat until $b$ is chosen:

1. Compute the change in $E$ for three choices of timestep:
   $$ a = \Delta E|_{\frac{1}{2}\Delta t} \\ b = \Delta E|_{\Delta t} \\ c = \Delta E|_{2\Delta t}. $$

   We then choose a new time-step for this iteration:

   - If all three are positive (suggesting $\Delta t$ is not sufficiently small): set $\Delta t \to \frac{1}{4} \Delta t$.
   - Else pick the smallest (i.e. negative with max value) of $a$,$b$,$c$ and set $\Delta t \to $ the corresponding value.

My thinking is that this allows $\Delta t$ to change quite rapidly (exponentially) when navigating rapidly-changing $E$ landscapes; the stable domain of $\Delta t$ for the current local landscape can be quickly reached.

This is quite a simple and naive algorithm, so I expect it's a simple instance of some category of adaptive time-step algorithms. Does this algorithm have a name, or does it belong to some established class of time-adaptation techniques? I am looking for a name to correctly describe this type of time-adaptation in a paper.

Comment: If none of $a$, $b$, or $c$ is suitable, why not set $\Delta t \rightarrow \frac{1}{8} \Delta t$, so that all three of the new $a$, $b$, and $c$ are fresh?

Comment: @EricTowers Oh yea good idea!

Comment: How much more expensive is $\nabla E(\vec\theta)$ compared to $E(\vec\theta)$, because if the difference is really that big you could also do something like [golden-section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search) for a couple of iterations before updating $\Delta\vec\theta$, which only requires some estimated upper bound for $\Delta t$.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen that's very interesting, thanks for the link! The gradient will be between 100 to ~5000 times more expensive to compute than a point. Actually I'm applying the method to minimize spaces of varying dimension and am not sure I can reason a scaling upper bound!

Comment: Maybe you could also use $2\,\Delta t$ as a guess for the upper bound for the golden-section search. If $\Delta t$ is too small it should still exponentially grow with the number of iterations (of calculating $\Delta\vec\theta$).